# XT1039 cannot get 5.1 OTA if I am root (but still on Stock 4.4.4)?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, ota-update, 5.1-lollipop

I own a XT1039 (moto g 4g 1st gen) and currently have unlocked bootloader and rooted.
Yet, I am on stock rom 4.4.4 and 21.11.56.peregrine_retgb.retgball.en.GB

I just contacted motorola on chat and they informed me that:
1) there is only OTA for updating to 5.1 (no way to download or load by pc Motorola Device Manager)
2) cannot guarantee that I will get a notification for the update because I m root.

I see,[here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/general/official-motorola-lollipop-update-news-t3001015)
that my device should already have the update

Any help, please?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to install the OTA due to having root, which modifies /system.  The OTA will check this, and will fail.  Being bootloader unlocked is fine, but you'd want to get back to 100% stock, then wait to see if you receive the OTA notification.

Comment: thank you very much! could you recommend a way to get the upgrade without unrooting?

Comment: I believe you have to flash the stock system and recovery img files via fastboot.  You won't lose your data at all or have to set up your phone.  You should then be able to accept the OTA successfully.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to do the process of flashing the update manually. Since you are already rooted, you could also try custom roms (if you are adventurous).

Comment: We're looking for detailed answers here. Please see [how do I write a good answer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [edit] your answer to incorporate the required steps.